# Casting a composed Function to a subclass of Function

Tags: java, casting

This is what I would like to do:

I want to have an abstract class `Operation` implement the `Function` interface, and then have subclasses like `OpA` inheriting it. `Operation` is a `Function` from `Integer` to `Integer`, and I want to be able to use `Function.compose` and `Function.andThen` to compose `OpA`s. In code:

```
public abstract class Operation implements Function<Integer, Integer>
{
    // ...
}
public class OpA extends Operation
{
    // ...
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OpA a = new OpA();
        OpA b = new OpA();

        // vvv Problem here vvv
        Operation compose = (Operation) a.andThen(b);
    }
}
```

The problem is, despite `a.andThen(b)` is a `Function` from `Integer` to `Integer`, I cannot cast it to an `Operation`. A `java.lang.ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.function.Function$$Lambda$56/1571051291 cannot be cast to operation.Operation
at application.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

To be honest I wasn't really expecting it to work like that to start with, but for my purpose I REALLY need the composed function to be an `Operation`. So for my question I am asking for a way to make function composition return an object that's type-compatible with `Operation`. Anything that works is fine: I'm willing to write my own `composed` and `andThen` function if necessary (but I don't know how to), though a neat fix is always welcomed.

Comment: can you explain why it has to be an `Operation` as opposed to a `Function`?

Comment: @Eugene It has to be `Operation` because `Operation` class contains some other custom methods. The code that uses those methods was written by my colleague and I would not like to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if suppose you want to implement a `Sum`, it could be done like this:

```
static class Sum extends Operation {

    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer x) {
        return x + 1;
    }

    public Operation andThen(Operation after) {
        return new Operation() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer x) {
                return after.apply(Sum.this.apply(x));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Calling it:

```
Sum a = new Sum();
Sum b = new Sum();

Operation composed = a.andThen(b);
System.out.println(composed.apply(2)); // 4
```

Comment: Hah, thanks! It seems so obvious after you showed me how =).

Comment: One thing to note, I ended up putting `compose` and `andThen` methods in `Operation` class, so now I only have to write this code once. Works like a charm!